BoringSSL-GRPC Unsupported option '-G' for target 'arm64-apple-ios10.0' for Swift Project
After updating to the XCode 16 Beta, while building the app, I get this error.
I've tried pod deintegrate, pod install, pod update, changing Minimum Deployment version.
Also tried removing the -GCC_WARN_INHIBIT_ALL_WARNINGS compiler flag but it didn't help.
Below are the code snippets which I tried, but did'nt work for my swift project.
if target.name == 'BoringSSL-GRPC'
      target.source_build_phase.files.each do |file|
        if file.settings && file.settings['COMPILER_FLAGS']
          flags = file.settings['COMPILER_FLAGS'].split
          flags.reject! { |flag| flag == '-GCC_WARN_INHIBIT_ALL_WARNINGS' }
          file.settings['COMPILER_FLAGS'] = flags.join(' ')
        end
      end
    end
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    if target.name == 'BoringSSL-GRPC'
      target.source_build_phase.files.each do |file|
        if file.settings && file.settings['COMPILER_FLAGS']
          flags = file.settings['COMPILER_FLAGS'].split
          flags.reject! { |flag| flag == '-GCC_WARN_INHIBIT_ALL_WARNINGS' }
          file.settings['COMPILER_FLAGS'] = flags.join(' ')
        end
      end
    end
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '13.0'
    end
  end
end

Is there any way to fix it?

This question is similar to: BoringSSL-GRPC unsupported option '-G' for target 'arm64-apple-ios15.0'. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
